# Android studios emulator error

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed android studio in Ubuntu 17.10, but when I created a ADV and try to start it I receive a bunch of error, I have already searched on Google, but none of solution that i found resolved my problem.

I have already installed all the libs that the [android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html?gclid=CjwKCAiAu4nRBRBKEiwANms5W9QWIO7O8XshX36RDP6g8XhGfhqq8ZyCBTDD9BJ3LYWwsAQhFpJjVxoClV8QAvD_BwE) website asks

Here is the error that I receive

```
16:52   Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
16:52   Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing
16:52   Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
16:52   Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
16:52   Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
16:52   Emulator: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
16:52   Emulator: Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
16:52   Emulator: Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
16:52   Emulator: Value in failed request:  0x0
16:52   Emulator: Serial number of failed request:  31
16:52   Emulator: Current serial number in output stream:  32
16:52   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes because of `libstdc++` **C++ Runtime Library**

You first have to install the following packages if there not on the system  `lib64stdc++6` and `mesa-utils` as follows

```
sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6 mesa-utils
```

Then symlink the libraries to the android sdk tools path

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++
sudo mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.og  ##making a copy of the file
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++
```

In many cases `libstdc++` path as follows

```
~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
sudo mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.og 
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++
```

I hope its Work for you.

Comment: when I try to enter on `~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++` I receive `Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++: No such file or directory`, would you know why I don't have this folder?

And I already have this packages installed

Comment: i don't know exactly what is the case scenario. I have faced same issue in 15.4 .